# Matplotlib sliders rescale colorbar when used to change clim

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I'm trying to use matplotlib sliders to interactively adjust the upper and lower limits of the colour scale of a figure. Although the sliders work, the size of the colorbar also changes with the limits. The desired outcome is that the colorbar dimensions don't change when clim is changed via the sliders.

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


# Generate random data
x = np.linspace(-1,1,101)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,101)
c = np.random.random((101,101))


# Plot data
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.3)

img = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,c, cmap = "inferno")
cbar = plt.colorbar(img)


# Add Sliders
c_min = np.min(c) #the min and max range of the sliders
c_max = np.max(c)

ax_cmin = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03]) #positions sliders beneath plot
ax_cmax  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])

s_cmin = Slider(ax_cmin, 'min', c_min, c_max, valinit=c_min) #defines sliders
s_cmax = Slider(ax_cmax, 'max', c_min, c_max, valinit=c_max)

def update(val):
    _cmin = s_cmin.val
    _cmax = s_cmax.val
    img.set_clim([_cmin, _cmax])
    img.update()

s_cmin.on_changed(update)
s_cmax.on_changed(update)


plt.show()
```

I've tried removing the colorbar inside the "update" function prior to updating the plot and then redrawing it as well as adding a cax argument to the colorbar, but it changes nothing.

I'm running python 3.5.6 and matplotlib 3.0.0 in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: the sliders work as expected for me on matplotlib v3.3.0, although I don't think you need `img.update()` in there

Comment: You're right, the "img.update" is redundant, removing it actually seems to make the interactivity smoother, thanks. I found that in 3.0.0 one needs to call cbar.ax.relim() to avoid the colorbar changing dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue. Calling "cbar.ax.relim()" at the beginning of the "update" function allows one to change the clim on the sliders without resizing the colorbar. Also tmdavison is correct that "img.update()" is not needed.

The "update" function in the example above should be replaced with the following:

```
def update(val):
    cbar.ax.relim()
    _cmin = s_cmin.val
    _cmax = s_cmax.val
    img.set_clim([_cmin, _cmax])
```